# vert.x Integration with grails web application

Tags: grails, groovy, vert.x

I am planning to learn vert.x. I want to integrate vert.x with my grails web application and angularjs. But i dont know where to start and how to start? i searched in google but didn't find solution. can any one give me example to integrate with grails web application?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great place to start
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/grails-vertx-websockets

Comment: and also one of the first hits when doing a web search for `grails vert.x`...